# React Variable Assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I define a variable with some information I'm fetching from an API, some of the variables are undefined or are undefined once. But once I save again in VS Code, they get their respective values.

```
function Pokemon() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [poke, setPoke] = useState({})
    const [pokestats, setPokestats] = useState([]);
    const [species, setSpecies] = useState('')
    let types = []

    async function getPokeData() {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
        setPoke(data)
        setSpecies(data?.species?.url)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getPokeData();
    }, [])
}

</div>
    <PokeEvolve species={species} />
</div>
```

Comment: Most likely is the props im sending to PokeEvolve that are getting undefined

Comment: `id` should be in your effect hook dependencies array